# Accessing container resource variables in Azure Devops YAML Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Using Azure Devops YAML Pipelines and trying to have a pipeline trigger on a container being pushed to an ACR.

According to the documentation in the link below, I should be able to access the tag and other information related to the image using variables like RESOURCES_CONTAINER_IDENTIFIER_TAG that should be available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema

However, I see no trace of variables from Containers or Repositories. It works fine with Pipelines and I haven't tested Builds. To be clear, the pipeline is triggered fine but inside the pipeline I cannot see which tag triggered it.

So is there something special that needs to be done here or is it released in the documentation but not working yet?

Comment: Hi, please run command `env | sort` in bash task and then check whether the `RESOURCES_CONTAINER_IDENTIFIER_TAG` variable exists there.

Comment: Already did that. It exists for pipeline resources but not for repo nor containers.

Comment: Hi Mats, sorry for the delay. As I know the `resources.container.<Alias>.tag` should work after Sprint 159. Normally we're in Sprint 164, so it should work for your situation. If you specify the repository like `repository : xxx/xxx:v1-tag`, the `resources.container.xxx.tag` will output `v1-tag` and if you use something like `repository : xxx/xxx`, the `resources.container.xxx.tag` will output the latest tag. Can you share more details about how you define the yaml and how you design the test?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? If it persists, could you please share the info about your yaml and corresponding log.

Comment: I did get a response from the Azure Devops team that this feature indeed was not yet implemented, even though the docs say so. They adviced me to post a feature request which I did. Hope it will be implemented soon. :)

Comment: I've confirmed with the team there several days ago and this feature is supported. I think you've noticed that the team there has deleted the wrong response. Hope it makes some help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#container-resource-variables) states:

`resources.container.<Alias>.tag` is what you want and it should work because this feature is supported since Sprint 159. (Now it's Sprint 164.)

Sample yaml:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: ACRResource1
    type: ACR
    azureSubscription: ARM
    resourceGroup: xxx
    registry: xxx
    repository: xxx/docker-acr:v1-tag
  - container: ACRResource2
    type: ACR
    azureSubscription: ARM
    resourceGroup: xxx
    registry: xxx
    repository: xxx/docker-acr
```

Sample output:

```
resources.container.ACRResource1.tag = v1-tag
resources.container.ACRResource2.tag = v10-tag  (latest tag value)
```

Make sure you configured the yaml and settings well and created [valid service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection).

Comment: It did work after creating a new Service Connection. The webhook was successfully setup and the pipeline ran but for weird reason the container and its metadata was not read with the old Service Connection.